# Require help to get access form to insert values into query

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

Good day,

I need some help with MS Access and a query. My SQL query takes entries from the a table and copies it to the same table with the **month** field changed to a different value. For example it would take all the payroll entries for Jan, copy them and change the month to Feb.

The SQL looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (month, field, field, field)
SELECT "FEB", field, field, field
FROM example_table
WHERE month = "JAN"
```

It selects all the entries for JAN and then copies and pastes it into the same table and changes the month to FEB.

My question is, how can I run this query in MS Access to get the "FEB and "JAN" field values (from the above example) from a form?

Maybe the way that I'm trying to do this is not the best method, if there is another way to get the same results please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're after, but if `YourForm` has a text box named `txtFirstMonth` where you would type in "JAN" and another named `txtSecondMonth` where you would type in "FEB", this should give you the equivalent of your sample query.

```
INSERT INTO example_table ([month], field, field, field)
SELECT
    Forms!YourForm!txtSecondMonth AS [month],
    field,
    field, 
    field
FROM example_table
WHERE [month] = Forms!YourForm!txtFirstMonth;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this very much looks like what I need. I tried running the query though, and it gives me a **Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.** error. Could it be the difference in how Access needs SQL to be formatted?

Comment: Its ok, the error was due to the fields in my query not being in the same order as they are in the table. Your help was invaluable HansUp, thank you very much.